# IPython QtConsole: select text to copy?

Tags: clipboard, ipython

Is there any way to make QtConsole copy marked (selected) text automatically to clipboard? OS: Linux, GUI: KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose if you can do it with `QtGui.QWidget` it is doable with QtConsole, but it will require patching the application I guess. One of the reason is that the Rich widget have 2 copy action , only the code without the `In[]` and continuation (`...:`) prompt, or with it.